# create an sql table of the selected inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create an sql table of the selected inner join table.

I would not only like to select the inner join of the two tables, but to create the table in the DB which exactly resembles that inner join. How could I achieve this?

Comment: google [`create table from select mysql`](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=create+table+from+select+mysql)

Answer (score 0):

to select from only one of two joined tables:

```
select B.* from myTableA as A inner join myTableB as B on .....
```

assuming you have a table myTableC that has the same columns as myTableB then

```
select B.* into myTableC from myTableA as A inner join myTableB as B on .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two tables `table1`, `table2` which you wish to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
INTO newTable IN 'YourDatabase.mdb'
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```

You may omit out the `IN 'YourDatabase.mdb'` phrase if you just want the new table to be in the same database as the one where tables `table1` and `table2` currently are.  The example I gave above is for `MySQL` and you may have to change it for other flavors of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the timed reply.

I could achieve this using,

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
  SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 
  table1.id = table2.id
```

This is 
       "`CREATE TABLE...............SELECT.... statement`"